# BlueJ - 'no suitable method found' for sort method

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, bluej

I'm using *BlueJ* for a project. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;`
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class SongSorter extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel main, header, buttons1, buttons2, labels, texts, SongPanel;
    private JTextField Title, Artist, Album, Year;
    private JLabel credits, title, artist, album, year;
    private JButton add, shuffle, sortTitle, sortArtist, sortAlbum, sortYear;
    private JTextArea RecordsText;
    private Song s;
    private List<Song> playlist;

public SongSorter()
{
    Container c = this.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
    c.setBackground( Color.BLACK );

    main = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
    main.setSize( 200, 200 );
    c.add( main);

    // for buttons
    header = new JPanel( new GridLayout(4, 1) );
    main.add( header, "North" );

    buttons1 = new JPanel( new FlowLayout() );
    header.add( buttons1 );

    add = new JButton( "Add" );
    shuffle = new JButton( "Shuffle" );

    buttons1.add( add );
    buttons1.add( shuffle );

    buttons2 = new JPanel( new FlowLayout() );
    header.add( buttons2 );

    sortTitle = new JButton( "Title" );
    sortArtist = new JButton( "Artist" );
    sortAlbum = new JButton( "Album" );
    sortYear = new JButton( "Year" );

    buttons2.add( sortTitle );
    buttons2.add( sortArtist );
    buttons2.add( sortAlbum );
    buttons2.add( sortYear );

    texts = new JPanel( new FlowLayout() );
    header.add( texts );

    Title = new JTextField( "Title", 10 );
    Artist = new JTextField( "Artist", 10 );
    Album = new JTextField( "Album", 10 );
    Year = new JTextField( "Year", 10 );

    title = new JLabel("Title: ");
    artist = new JLabel("Artist: ");
    album = new JLabel("Album: ");
    year = new JLabel("Year: ");

    texts.add( title );
    texts.add( Title );
    texts.add( artist );
    texts.add( Artist );
    texts.add( album );
    texts.add( Album );
    texts.add( year );
    texts.add( Year );

    // where the user will see the record of songs listed
    SongPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(1, 1) );
    main.add( SongPanel, "Center" );
    SongPanel.setSize(100, 100);

    RecordsText = new JTextArea();
    RecordsText.setWrapStyleWord( true );
    RecordsText.setLineWrap( true );
    RecordsText.setTabSize( 100 );
    SongPanel.add( RecordsText );

    playlist = new ArrayList<Song>();

    // sorting comparators
    final SongByTitle t = new SongByTitle();
    final SongByArtist a = new SongByArtist();
    final SongByAlbum b = new SongByAlbum();
    final SongByYear y = new SongByYear();

    // time for buttons and shit
    // add and shuffle
    add.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                String t = Title.getText();
                String a = Artist.getText();
                String b = Album.getText();
                int y = Integer.parseInt( Year.getText() );

                s = new Song(t, a, b, y);
                playlist.add( s );

                RecordsText.append( s.print() );
            }
        }
    );

    shuffle.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                Collections.shuffle( playlist );
                RecordsText.setText( playlist.toString() );
            }
        } );

    // sorting buttons
    sortTitle.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                Collections.sort( playlist, t );
                RecordsText.setText( playlist.toString() );
            }
        } );

    sortArtist.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                Collections.sort( playlist, a );
                RecordsText.setText( playlist.toString() );
            }
        } );

    sortAlbum.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                Collections.sort( playlist, b );
                RecordsText.setText( playlist.toString() );
            }
        } );

    sortYear.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
            {
                Collections.sort( playlist, y );
                RecordsText.setText( playlist.toString() );
            }
        } );
    }
}

class SongByTitle implements Comparator<Song>
    {
        public int compare( Song a, Song b )
        {
            return a.getTitle().compareTo( b.getTitle() );
        }
    }

    class SongByArtist implements Comparator<Song>
    {
        public int compare( Song a, Song b )
        {
            return a.getArtist().compareTo( b.getArtist() );
        }
    }

    class SongByAlbum implements Comparator<Song>
    {
        public int compare( Song a, Song b )
        {
            return a.getAlbum().compareTo( b.getAlbum() );
        }
    }

    class SongByYear implements Comparator<Song>
    {
        public int compare( Song a, Song b )
        {
            if( a.getYear() < b.getYear() ) return -1;
            else if(a.getYear() > b.getYear() ) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    }
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
no suitable method found for sort(java.util.List<Song>, SongByTitle)
    method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
     (no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that argument type SongByTitle conforms to formal parameter type java.util.Comparator<? super T>)
    method java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>) is not applicable
     (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

I've been searching for an hour or so online on what I can do to fix this; I've changed my playlist from an ArrayList to a List only, I've tried to just call the Comparator inside the sort() method itself - I feel like I've tried everything and yet it STILL doesn't work.

Whenever I try to compile it, it always highlights my '.sort' part. I feel like I've run out of places to go to for asking for advice regarding the matter.

I also read the other questions here on stackoverflow. I've been surfing through these pages for an hour now, and still no clue. I don't know where I got it wrong. It seems fine by me.

Whoever can help regarding this will be fully appreciated. (You'll help me sleep earlier once I get this done. XD)

--

oh, just in case, here's the other classes in the program.

**Comparator interface**

```
public interface Comparator<Song> 
{
    int compare( Song a, Song b );
}
```

**Song class**

```
public class Song
{
    String title, artist, album;
    int year;

public Song(String t, String a, String b, int y)
{
    title = t;
    artist = a;
    album = b;
    year = y;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public String getArtist()
{
    return artist;
}

public String getAlbum()
{
    return album;
}

public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public String print()
{
    String t = this.getTitle();
    String a = this.getArtist();
    String b = this.getAlbum();
    int y = this.getYear();

    String song = t + 
        " by " + a + "; Album: " + b + ", " + y + "\n";
    return song;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return title + " by " + artist 
       + "; Album: " + album + ", " + year + "\n";
}
}
```

**Runner class**

```
public class SongRunner
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame f = new SongSorter();
        f.setSize( 200, 200 );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        f.setVisible( true );
        f.setResizable( false );
    }
}
```

Comment: That error is at compilation time or at execution time? Can you say the line in which error is?

Comment: the error appears whenever I try to compile the code. It highlights the '.sort' part of this line: "Collections.sort( playlist, t );"

Comment: the error message is basically telling you that you're passing two arguments to `sort`, but the second one isn't a comparator.

Comment: @JanDvorak oh, okay... so the classes that I made to implement the Comparator class doesn't work? D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build your own Comparator interface, Java already has one. What you need, is to build objects of Java's Comparator interface and pass these to Collections.sort

You can even do this within your Song class, for multiple comparators, like so:

```
public class Song {

// ...

public static Comparator<Song> getAlbumComparator() {
    return new Comparator<Song>() {
        public int compare(YourClass one, YourClass two) {
            return(songA.getAlbum().compareTo(songB.getAlbum());
        }
    };
}

// Other comparators
}
```

You would then call:

```
Collections.sort(playlist, Song.getAlbumComparator());
```

Make sure you also delete your own Comparator interface.

Comment: ahh! now it compiled. :D Thank you for this! XD Now I'll be off to continuing to make the program work. :P tho I wanted to ask (if ever), did my program not work because the code was redundant or something? You mentioned that I don't have to build my own Comparator interface for Java already has one. Was that also part in the reason why my code wouldn't compile in the first place? ^^;

Comment: Yes, the problem was that Collections.sort needs to be passed an object which implements Java's default Comparable interface. Because you had specified your own interface also called Comparable, your Comparators were implementing that instead of Java's default, so Collections.sort wasn't being passed an acceptable parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You creating the SongByTitle, SongByArtist, SongByAlbum , SongByYear classes **inside** the SongSorter() constructor.

To fix this issue you need to creae the SongByTitle, SongByArtist, SongByAlbum , SongByYear classes **outside** the SongSorter() constructor.

```
public class SongSorter extends JFrame
   public SongSorter()
   {//here the problem starts
         class  SongByTitle{

        }
        class SongByArtist{

        }
        class SongByAlbum{

        }
        class SongByYear{

       } 
   }//here the problem ends
}
```

**correction**

```
public class SongSorter extends JFrame
   public SongSorter()
   {
   }
   class  SongByTitle{

   }
   class SongByArtist{

   }
   class SongByAlbum{

   }
   class SongByYear{

   } 
}
```

Comment: this was actually what my code previously looked like before I was tweaking it to see if putting the classes inside or outside would make a difference. I tried to compile it again, still the same error.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I ignore if this is an error in the copy/paste of your code or really is here, but in the code you have pasted in your question you are declaring Comparator classes inside the constructor. In this way class don't exists when you try to use them.

You must extract this classes:

```
public class SongSorter extends JFrame
{
    ...

    public SongSorter() { ... }

    class SongByTitle implements Comparator<Song> { ... }

    class SongByArtist implements Comparator<Song> { ... }

    class SongByAlbum implements Comparator<Song> { ... }

    class SongByYear implements Comparator<Song> { ... }
}
```

Is this your matter?

Comment: no, what I'm wondering about is why the sort() method doesn't compile.. I've put the classes outside of the SongSorter class previously, yet it still didn't compile :(

Comment: You can try invoking sort() method like this: `Collections.<Song>sort()`

Comment: I also tried that before, but it didn't work :( Still had the same error

Comment: I had ignored you were using your own interface ;-). Sorry